# Migrating Web App to Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am trying to move a web app to Angular2. I had successfully moved HTML & CSS to angular's component.html & component.css respectively. However, I am having trouble with .js files.

How do I incorporate .js file into component.ts?

.js file:

```
A = (function(w){
    var init = function(){};
    var scrollToElement = function(){};
}(window);

$(document).ready(function() {
  A.init();
  A.scrollToElement();
  ....
});
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $.getScript('assets/js/script.js');
  }
}
```

Is this correct? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are the two files incorporated or implemented?

Comment: Can the two files co-exists? Or I need to move content of js to ts or incorporate js to ts?

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you write js code in TypeScript in component.ts
and there is no need of jQuery's document.ready, window.load etc functions
because angular have its own life cycle hooks
see this --> [See This](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

Using feedback by @SreedevR & @mlMughal, here's how i did it.

In index.html, I include the script file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
   <base href="/">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

   <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

In component.ts:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
A:any;

constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {}
ngAfterViewInit(){
   A.init();
   A.scrollToElement();
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please include the js in your main html file and you can call the fiction in the component.

Eg: If you script file is test.js please include that in the html file and call any function declared in it in the component like

```js
f(){
    new test();
  }
```

Hope this is clear now

Comment: Most of the functions in js are called when document.ready. How do i do that in component.ts?

Comment: You can either migrate the js to the Type Script or if you are still want to use js Please use angular "ngOnInit()" https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit  which is equivilant to document.ready

Comment: @Melissa as i answered above you should have to catch appropriate life cycle hook  for your problem replacement for document.ready is ngOninit() and for others like onPageLoad(), onUnload(), onBeforeUnload() e.t.c you have to catch different hooks